# How do I launch "Live Beans Graph" in Spring Tool Suite 4.10.0?

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to run the project that the tutorial (https://youtu.be/p8AdyMlpmPk?t=651) gives, using Spring Tool Suite 4.10.0, though I don't see the "Spring Tools" or "Live Beans Graph", as shown in the image below, how do I do?

[image]